# Infinite file size loading as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to load a big xml feed within ActionScript3. The problem is that the progress event indicate that the bytesTotal is zero and this result in a infinite loading sequence. The complete handler is never triggered.

This is what is do.

```
loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadDone);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, dataAnalyzeProgress)
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, io_error);

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        loader.load(urlRequest);


protected function io_error(event:IOErrorEvent):void
    {
        trace("IO ERROR")
        trace(event.text)

    }

    protected function loadDone(event:Event):void
    {
        trace('DATA COMPLETE')

        trace(event.target.content)

    }

    protected function dataAnalyzeProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        trace((e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) *100+"%");     
        trace("Downloaded " + e.bytesLoaded + " out of " + e.bytesTotal + " bytes");    


        if(e.bytesTotal == 0)
        {
            loader.close();
        }
    }
```

Does somebody have a solution for this problem. I tried load it through curl i first, but still the same problem...

Comment: Why would you close the loader during a progress event?

Comment: If you can't load the file with curl/wget then this is probably not AS3 problem. Rather than you should check with the server.

Comment: It's not necessary but i did this to close te connection, but without  the loader.close, it wont work either

Comment: The problem is that it's a feed, provided by Third parties. I'm looking for some kind of workaround.

Comment: You are never telling the loader to load the URLRequest object.  I assume this is just a copy/paste error, since you describe seeing the logging you apply in the dataAnalyzeProgress method.  You should edit your question though.

Comment: @meddlingwithfire sorry, edited it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `URLLoader` class for loading xml data, not `Loader`. `Loader` class is for loading SWF and pictures (JPG, PNG, GIF).  Try these lines:

```
 var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadDone);
 loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, dataAnalyzeProgress)
 loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, io_error);

 var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
 loader.load(urlRequest);
```